# Migrating from carthage to swift package manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, carthage

I have a project that has multiple external dependencies as well as in house ones such as analytics, api, interfaces, that are all integrated with Carthage. I wanted to gradually migrate all of them to SPM starting with the analytics module.

I've restructured my analytics module to a package and integrated it to main my project using SPM (all worked well!). I did the same for all the other modules that also depend on analytics and removed the references from cartfile, .resolved and .private files.

The issue that I'm facing now is that I'm not sure how to remove the integration done by carthage. Even removing the reference from all cartfiles and from framework and libraries, when I run carthage bootstrap it looks like it still fetches that module and adds the framework to my Carthage folder, which I don't want to.

It's the first time I'm using Carthage, so I'm not sure if I might be missing some step when removing just one dependency. If anyone with more experience could help I'd really really appreciate it =]